# Why does \p{P} behave differently from \p{Ps}?

Tags: regex, unicode

Why does \p{P} when used in
`(^|\p{P})(?!,alpha,),*alpha,*`
behave differently from \p{Ps} used in
`(^|\p{Ps})(?!,alpha,),*alpha,*`
when used to process
`(,alpha,`
\p{P} matches whereas \p{Ps} does not match

Comment: The problem is with \p{Po}. 
For example,
`(^|[\p{P}-[\p{Po}]])(?!,alpha,),*alpha,*`
works as wanted. But I would still be interested in knowing why.

Comment: See the [list of chars matched with `\p{Ps}`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Ps/list.htm). All cateogries list: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Because `\p{P}` matches the `,` in your string, not `(`.

This is because you have a negative lookahead `(?!,alpha,)` after `\p{P}`. This means that "after 'any punctuation', there must not be the string `,alpha,`". Well, There *is* `,alpha,` after `(`, so `\p{P}` fails to match `(`. The regex engine moves forward one character, and tries again. This time, `\p{P}` matches `,` and there is no `,alpha,` after `,` (there is only `alpha,`!), and the rest of the match succeeds too, so the whole match succeeds. The matched string is `,alpha,`, without the `(`.

If you change the `\p{P}` to `\p{Ps}`, it will fail to match `(` just like before, but also fail to match `,`, causing the whole match the fail. Note that the `^` alternative doesn't get chosen, because even though the lookahead passes, your regex requires a `,` to immediately follow. But after the start of string, there is a `(` instead.

Comment: Thanks, it must be Sunday.